# Use highcharter inside a function

Tags: r, highcharts, r-highcharter

How do I use [highcharter](http://jkunst.com/highcharter/)::[hchart](http://jkunst.com/highcharter/hchart.html) inside a function?

Here is a simple line graph using the `hchart` function.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(highcharter)
library(nycflights13)

flights_2 <- flights %>% 
  mutate(dep_mo = ymd(str_c(year, month, "01", sep = "-"))) %>% 
  group_by(dep_mo) %>% 
  summarize(arr_delay = mean(arr_delay, na.rm = TRUE))

hchart(flights_2, 
       type = "line", 
       hcaes(x = dep_mo, y = arr_delay), 
       name = "Average Arrival Delay")
```

When I try to write a function to create the same graph I get an error.

```
h_fun <- function(df, x, y) {
  hchart(df, 
         type = "line",
         hcaes(x = x, y = y),
         name = "Average Arrival Delay"
         )
 }

 h_fun(df = flights_2, x = dep_mo, y = arr_delay)
```

This is the error message: `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Binding not found: x.`

When I traceback the error it seems `hchart` is using `dplyr::mutate_`. This leads me to *believe* the error has something to do with NSE and maybe `hchart` needs something akin to `ggplot2::aes_string()` ([link](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/aes_.html)). However, I can't find any documentation on a similar function in `highcharter`.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need to use `enquo()` & `quo_name()` together with `hcaes_string`

- `enquo()` captures the expression supplied as argument by the user & returns a quosure.
- `quo_name()` squashes the quosure and transforms it into a string.

Watch Hadley explained `tidyeval` in this [5min video](https://youtu.be/nERXS3ssntw) if you haven't heard about it. More on `tidyeval` [here](https://maraaverick.rbind.io/2017/08/tidyeval-resource-roundup/)

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(highcharter)
library(nycflights13)

flights_2 <- flights %>% 
  mutate(dep_mo = ymd(str_c(year, month, "01", sep = "-"))) %>% 
  group_by(dep_mo) %>% 
  summarize(arr_delay = mean(arr_delay, na.rm = TRUE))

h_fun2 <- function(df, x, y) {
  x <- enquo(x)
  y <- enquo(y)
  hchart(df, 
         type = "line",
         hcaes_string(quo_name(x), quo_name(y)),
         name = "Average Arrival Delay"
  )
}

h_fun2(df = flights_2, x = dep_mo, y = arr_delay)
```

[image]

**Edit**: as of April 18, 2018, the development version of `highcharter` supports `tidyeval` so `h_fun2` can be rewritten as:

```r
h_fun2 <- function(df, x, y) {
  x <- enexpr(x)
  y <- enexpr(y)
  hchart(df, 
         type = "line",
         hcaes(!!x, !!y),
         name = "Average Arrival Delay"
  )
}
```

Comment: I would be careful because the `hchart()` function itself doesn't support tidy evaluation so you can't use operators like `!!` (bang-bang). So most of the things Hadley talks about you might not be able to do directly. But of course `quo_name(enquo())` is a good general way to get the "name" of an unquoted variable passed to a function.

Comment: Thanks for the headsup! Hope we will see `tidyeval` in ggplot soon

Comment: Worked like a charm. **Thank you!**

Comment: @jordan: FYI, `highcharter` does support tidy evaluation now after the latest commit. Check my edit for more info!

Comment: @Tung Even better. Thank you.